# unable to get location of mobile using geolocation in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, geolocation

i am working on a web app which need to get the location of a person on mobile. It is a web browser based application. I googled to know how to get the location and i found the following code.

```
    <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }
  window.onload = getLocation();
</script>
```

i ran it in mobile safari on my iphone and also enabled location service for safari and also allowed it to get my location on prompt. But when the page is loaded i have an empty page. Is there any other way of getting location of the user or what am i doing wrong here? I want the exact location. What i mean by that is in which area or block the user is. I used iphone 4 with ios 6.1. I used edge to load the page.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am looking for an answer now :/